# What translator engine does Safari on Mac use?

Tags: macos, mac, safari, web-browser, websites

Simple as that. What?

(My guess is it's Deepl.com as it appears far superior to Google Translator. And to my knowledge, that is the only publicly available translator model that is better than Google's.)

Comment: The Apple Neural Engine?  Whatever it is, the language coverage is tiny compared to Google translate, and even Deepl.com has 18 more.

Comment: Yes, indeed, I only found out about its existence tomorrow, and when I tested it, the translate option only came up in some major languages. Sad. This difference implies that it is definitely neither Google or Deepl. Do you know for fact that "Apple Neural Engine" exists for this purpose? If so, please submit an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: All I see if vague stuff that comes up if you google "apple neural engine translate app" or something similar.